# Form.value remove: null and empty values''" (Angular/TypesScript)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form.value like this...

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "foo",
  "last_name": "",
  "xxxxx": null
}
```

I would like remove object null or empty ("").

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "foo"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://pt.stackoverflow.com or should be rewritten in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso
**ES6 / ES2015:**

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => (!obj[k] && obj[k] !== undefined) && delete obj[k]);
```

Comment: Answer in English on this site, even if the question is not in English (preferably don't answer before the author has translated it.)